# How to check if multiple words contain in a CSV column?

Tags: python, csv

I found several similar questions online on how to find a word in a specific column in a CSV file however, I didn't find any on checking multiple words. 
Here's the problem:

```
words = ‘something’
for row in data:
    if words not in row[‘column header name’]:
        writer.writerow[row]
```

The above code prints all the data into a csv file. It also checks if 'something-...' is in the row['column header name'] then it skips that row. 
For example, in that column, each cell contains strings such as 'something-asdas' or 'something-aaaa'. It's checking part of that string and skips it.

Goal:

```
words = (‘something’, 'word' , 'dada')
for row in data:
    if words not in row[‘column header name’]:
        writer.writerow[row]
```

When I try to do that, I get TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not tuple. 
Any ideas on how to fix that problem? I tried to iterate through the tuple but then my csv file will have duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the built-in [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) checking if any of the words in the tuple is present in a row:

```
words = ("something", "word" , "dada")
for row in data:
    # skipping rows containing any of the "words"
    if not any(word in row["column header name"] for word in words):
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Of course, this assumes that `row` is a dictionary and you've used the [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader).

Comment: Oh wow, I tried using any() earlier but didn't work. Your answers works however! Thanks so much.